# How is signal strength (RSS) measurement done on Bluetooth and Zigbee ?

Tags: signal, antenna, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, zigbee

My question is related to an observation that I made.
I tested BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy [ti2541/nRF51822) and ZigBee (ti cc2531) against each other on jumpiness of the signal strength (RSSI). Both use the same freq. and same antenna design (ANO43).

In my experiment I found out that the BLE modules were much more jumpy, especially when a person was in range (only in range not in line of sight). On the ZigBee module it was much more stable.

Does someone has an explanation for this or can give me more background information about how i can find out how the measurement on the modules is made.

Thanks!

Comment: were Tx/Rx orientation/direction optimized?  RSSI Noise can come from co-channel or adjacent channel interference or reflection interference (Ricean fading) or antenna return loss changes within spectral band or differences in modulation?  Sounds like Ricean effects with signal pointed in wrong direction??

Comment: The antennas were all oriented vertical. Ricean fading is new to me, but its really interesting, thanks ! Modulation might be different. :-/

Comment: When your signals are marginal, Ricean fading is dominant cause of drop outs and slightest aim direction or position gets out of a null closer to a peak every 1/2 wavelength approx. Excessive Modulation of RSSI when close, indicates either antenna is badly tuned.

Answer (score 3):

RSSI is not a well-defined term. Every receiver has it's own specific way of estimating it; so the estimation you use for ZigBee might simply be more beneficial to its rssi guesstimate than the method you use for ble.

Also note that Bluetooth (ble not necessarily) is a frequency-hopping-intense standard. Which makes it even harder to cone up with a reasonable rssi formula. Average SNR? Worst SNR in a full hop cycle? BER after decoding? Before?

In conclusion: RSSI is not a scientific measure. It's about as good as the shampoo bottle saying "now 30% shinier hair"

Now, RSS might just be received signal strength in means of physical power - but that is also not a very helpful term by means of digital communication over that link, because what counts is receiver SNR, and that is a whole different story, especially for devices in ISM bands.

Comment: Thx, Marcus. BLE has only 3 Advertise Channels and I am not sure if they even do channelhopping.  What do you think: How does the modulation type impact the RSSI ?

Comment: @RobAnderson that's the whole point I'm trying to make: **noone** knows what RSSI means for your device. It's undefined. It could just be the number of dogs in your neighborhood, for example.